# Where did the word red-tapism come from?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, suffixes, neologisms

What is the origin of the word **red-tapism**?

And what does it actually mean?

*[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/red-tapism)* says it first appeared in the mid-19th century in the
*[Cobbett's Weekly Political Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_Register)*, a London paper. Searching deeper, I discovered that the owner, William Cobbett, supported expanding suffrage, raising the minimum pay for agricultural workers, and giving the poor food and employment. His newspaper was in print from 1802 until his death in 1836.

But in which year did *red-tapism* first appear, and did he coin it?

Can anyone provide more details on its origins?

Comment: Seems odd to be asking about "red-tapism" without even mentioning the very well-known term "red tape" - I would have thought one followed from the other.

Comment: Yes, it derives from *red tape*.

Answer (score 3):

**red-tapism, red-tapeism** (n.)

> Behaviour, practices, or attitudes associated with an excessive
> adherence to official rules and formalities; red tape.
>
> 1834   *Cobbett's Weekly Polit. Reg*. 28 June 323   The mysteries of
> ‘red-tapeism’. OED

[Link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cobbett_s_Weekly_Register/sqoTAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=red-tapeism&pg=PA823&printsec=frontcover) to this *Cobbett's* issue. This appears to be an unsigned letter beginning "*(From the Morning Herald 21. June.)*"  Note that *red-tapery* has an earlier first citation.

> Insistence on or preoccupation with red tape [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red-tapism)

**red-tapery** (n.)

> Rigid adherence to official rules and formalities; red tape. OED
>
> 1831   *Fraser's Mag.* **3** 654   These were the great heroes of the
> red-tapery

[Link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fraser_s_Magazine/BtgxAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22red-tapery%22&pg=PA654&printsec=frontcover) to this *Fraser's* issue.

**red-tapery, red-tapism**

> The system of red-tape; extreme adherence to official routine of
> formalities [*The Anglo-American Encyclopedia and Dictionary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Anglo_American_Encyclopedia_and_Dict/WKNRAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22red-tapery%22&pg=PA3384&printsec=frontcover)
> (1896)

(A search in Google Books turned up nothing earlier than the OED's first citations for either term.)